# infinity as an accumulation point on the Riemann Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-sphere

I got the following question from my complex analysis class ($\hat{\Bbb{C}}$ denotes the Riemann-sphere):

Does there exist a holomorphic function
$ f:\Bbb{C} \to \hat{\Bbb{C}}$ such that $f(n)=\infty$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$?

I would say that, since it's not specified that the function must not be constant, we can take $f(z) = \infty$ for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$, though I'm a little rusty in checking holomorphicity so I'm not sure whether it actually is holomorphic.

My other question is: is there any other holomorphic function satisfying this property? Perhaps $f(z) = \prod_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \frac{1}{z-n}$ is holomorphic on $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$?

My worry for this function is that for the Identity Theorem on $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$, since $\{f=\infty\}$ has an accumulation point in $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$, namely $\infty$, would imply that $f=\infty$ everywhere. But I'm not even sure whether $\infty$ is indeed an accumulation point in $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $f$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ or on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$? If it is the former, the fact that $\infty$ is an accumulation point is not relevant

Comment: $f$ is defined on $\Bbb{C}$. If I'm correct, this means that the set $\{n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ has no accumulation point (in $\Bbb{C}$) and therefore the second function I give with the infinite product should work fine, no?

Comment: Your product does not converge. To find a non constant $f$, think about $g(z)=\sin(\pi z)$.

Comment: $1/\sin(\pi z)$ will do.